# WiFi connection does not work on Ubuntu 14.04.4

Tags: networking, wireless

My wifi has been working well for a few weeks, but maybe after some upgrades of software, it does not work now and I can not find the signal of wifi now. I have tried to reinstall 14.04 for several times but it still fails to connect wifi. The information of my problem is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/19598727/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you had specified what Ubuntu release and which hardware you are using, but you might:

1. Remember the current kernel version (`uname -r`).
2. Reboot, holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, and selecting an older
   (lower version number) kernel to boot. Select progressively older
   kernels until you find one under which your wifi works.
3. Install the `linux-kernel-extras` package for the kernel version remembered
   from step 1. It will be called something like
   `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic`, (if you remembered `4.4.0-31`
   from step 1), YMMV.
4. Reboot.

I'm using a wifi dongle supported by the `rt2800usb` module, and had to do this recently.

Comment: sorry but it does not work for me

Comment: Read http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask . What did you try? "does not work for me" gives me only enough information to say "Oh. That's unfortunate.", and go on to other problems. I surmise that neither one of us is happy with that answer.